# Who was James Farber and why was he important to Unix?

Tags: history

I've been reading papers on [Plan 9 from Bell Labs](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/plan9). In the paper on [why Plan 9's not dead yet](http://www.cs.unm.edu/~fastos/05meeting/PLAN9NOTDEADYET.pdf), around page 18, the author mentions "Farber". Googling reveals this to be a James Farber, but all I can find is that he coauthored UNIX: The Complete Reference. Who was he, and why is he important to UNIX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only things additional I found:

- that he has his name on [3 Patents](http://patent.ipexl.com/inventor/James_M_Farber_1.html)
- Along with [4 papers he published on acm.org](http://dl.acm.org/author_page.cfm?id=81100450833&coll=DL&dl=ACM&trk=0&cfid=236874094&cftoken=85621006)
- He appears to be [working at Avaya](http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=2535491&authType=NAME_SEARCH&authToken=HW8O&locale=en_US&srchid=148068361375259557585&srchindex=1&srchtotal=2&trk=vsrp_people_res_name&trkInfo=VSRPsearchId:148068361375259557585,VSRPtargetId:2535491,VSRPcmpt%3aprimary)

I also found this reference to a conversation between Dave Korn and Jim Farber which I found funny. It was in the [comp.unix.user-friendly group over on Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.unix.user-friendly/H4JvCVd_cRg/tCLQGyx5sAkJ) from 1994.

*excerpt*

> Now for my psychologist hat. Editing skills are highly overlearned, so
>   switching editors in *unavoidably* anti-productive because of negative
>   transfer. It does not matter which editor you switch to or from. The
>   best editor is *always* the one you have used the most, or a proper
>   superset of it. That, by the way, was the advice Dave Korn got from
>   Jim Farber and myself back when he was first designing ksh. And I
>   think the world is better for it. Regards,
>
> ```
>                           Adam_V_Reed@ATT.com
> ```